# React Native FlatList: What's more performant, passing object or passing reference to object?

Tags: react-native, performance, redux, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I'm using MaterialTopTabNavigator with React Navigation v6. Each tab contains a FlatList. I have an array of objects that I want to render in each list, and this object is stored in Redux. I have two options:

1)Store the array in my parent component, and pass a full object to each item in FlatList:

```
const itemList = this.props.items.map(item => (
  <ItemDisplay item={item}/>
))
return (
  <FlatList data={itemList}/>
)
```

2)Store the array in the `<ItemDisplay>` component, and just pass a reference to each item in FlatList:

```
const itemIDs = this.props.items.map(item => item.ID)
const itemIDList = itemIDs.map(itemID => (
  <ItemDisplay itemID={itemID}/>
))
return (
  <FlatList data={itemIDList}/>
)
```

**What I Want To Know:** Which is more performant? In `1)` I'm storing the array from Redux in only one component (the parent), but passing a full object to each item instead of just an ID. But in `2)`, even though I'm passing only an ID instead of a full object, I'm importing the array from Redux in every child item.

I assume it depends on the size of the objects in the array, and the number of items being displayed, but can anyone give me insight into how these factors contribute?

Answer (score 0):

I think better solution is split data into 4 objects, each tab listen to 1 object by redux. So when u change the data, all the tab does not get re-render